# getStringExtra returns null value

Tags: java, android, null

I have a problem which is that the getStringExtra keeps return a null value. Why is that?

This is where the  string is added:

```
EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
String tnum = num.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(this,ConfirmOrder.class);
i.putExtra("tablenum",tnum);
```

And this the part the string is extracted:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String num = i.getStringExtra("tablenum");
```

Comment: How are you sending the intent and how are you receiving it?

Comment: What do you mean by sending the intent ._.

Comment: is tnum varaible null??

Comment: I think your String tnum is null. Try to Log the value of String just before i.putExtra("tablenum", tnum). Rest of the code seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

make sure tnum varaible is not null, try this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String num = i.getExtras().getStringExtra("tablenum");
```

or

```
Bundle ePzl= new Bundle();
ePzl.putString("tablenum", tnum);
Intent i = new Intent(this,ConfirmOrder.class);
i.putExtras(ePzl);
```

and

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String num = i.getExtras().getStringExtra("tablenum");
```

Answer (score 0):

put like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmOrder.class);
intent.putExtra("tablenum", tnum);
```

receive like this:

```
Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
String value = extras.getString("tablenum");
```